# Finding the Absolute Max and Min Using Complete the Square Of A Multivariable Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a homework problem that needs clarification. The problem says to find the absolute maxima and minima using completing the square where

$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + ((x^2)*y) + 4$  and $D = \{(x,y) : |x| \le 1, |y| \le 1\}$

I managed to find the solution using the example given from Paul's Online Math Notes on finding absolute maxima and minima. However, the question asks using completing the square. I tried using complete the square on $f(x,y)$ but it did not yield the form of $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = 1$, or at least a form resembling that. I have tried to substitute $x$ and $y$ with $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta$ respectively and tried to do it in terms of $f(\theta)$ but it did not seem to lead anywhere. I'm just not sure where exactly in the process does one have to complete the square. Is it applied on $f(x,y)$ or the derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the third term is $x^2y$ and not $xy$?

Comment: It is. The answer that I came to was an absolute maxima at (1,1) and minima at (0,0). It is also the answer given on the homework sheet.

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't complete the square here. WolframAlpha hasn't found an expression that would result from completing the square.

Comment: I'll talk to my prof. Maybe its a typo or something. Thank you for your help.